# ELK .security file issue

Tags: elasticsearch, upgrade

I have upgraded elastic 6.8 to 7.17.
and i have taken the .security-6 file backup as .security-6-reindexed.

but. while performing upgrade to 8.x.x version. nodes are showing the following error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Alias [.security] points to more than one index: [[.security-6/mdhasdfdfd], [.security-6-reindexed/kC-abcdefghi]]
```

and elastic user is not able to authenticate. any suggestion, how can i fix this.

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Even `elastic` superuser doesn't have access to restricted indices. To access to system indices you can create a new superduperuser [allow_restricted_indices](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/security-api-has-privileges.html#security-api-has-privileges-request-body) option.

```
#create the role
PUT _security/role/super_duper_user
{
  "indices": [
    {
      "names": [
        "*"
      ],
      "privileges": [
        "all"
      ],
      "allow_restricted_indices": true
    }
  ]
}
```

---

```
#add this role to a user
PUT _security/user/super_duper_user
{
  "password" : "l0ng-r4nd0m-p@ssw0rd",
  "roles" : [ "superuser", "super_duper_user" ],
  "full_name" : "Musab Dogan"
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To fix your error `Alias [.security] points to more than one index`, execute:

```
DELETE .security-6-reindexed/_alias/.security
```